# Angular: Unexpected Token import in scripts.bundle.js for jquery

Tags: jquery, angular

I am getting error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". Its take me to scripts.bundle.js , where it points to "import $ from 'jquery'`

i have installed jQuery and jquery/types through npm, as well as imported the dependencies in `angular-cli.json`.

Tried npm cache verify (didn't work).

None of the solutions worked so far.

I used

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery'; and used it, however even after commenting out all the jquery, " import $ from 'jquery' " is still there.

    Dependencies:
    "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
        "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
        "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
        "ng2-trim-directive": "^2.1.0",
        "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "typescript": "^2.6.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "typescript": "^2.4.2"
      }
    }
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.
Anand.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUgdT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you need to do next few steps:

- `npm install --save jquery`
- add `jquery` path to `scripts` array in `.angular-cli.json`
  like:

  > "scripts": [
  >                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  >               ...
  >              ]
- `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`
- add next section to `tsconfig.app.json`

  > "types": [
  >             "jquery"
  >           ]
- in your component import `jquery`

  > import * as $ from 'jquery';

and that's it :) hope it solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I had tried these steps,but didn't work. Fortunately i figured the cause to the scripts which i had added to angular-cli.json. It was boostrap-modal, which i got from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap-modal. Something which i messed it up. Thank you Again.

Comment: can u have a look into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003114/angular-forms-not-working-on-live-server

Comment: @AnandKumar what did you have messed up in your scripts cos I have having the same error. and I having a reference error with $ not found when I call $(document).foundation();