# Angular Forms not working on live server

Tags: angular, localhost, angular-reactive-forms

**I have used Reactive Form but its not working on live but on local it is working fine. The page gets refreshed while submitting the form. There is no error in console. **

I am new to Angular 4, any help will be highly appreciated.

Functionality is listed below:

signup.html

```
<form [formGroup]="signupuser" (ngSubmit)="signup(signupuser)">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input formControlName="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="25" trim >
                                <span class="for-signuperror" [hidden]="!(signupuser.controls.first_name.invalid && (signupuser.controls.first_name.touched || signUpFormTouched))">Please enter your First Name</span>
                                <span *ngIf="maxlength==25">Maximum Character should be 25</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input formControlName="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="25" trim>
                                <span class="for-signuperror" [hidden]="!(signupuser.controls.last_name.invalid && (signupuser.controls.last_name.touched || signUpFormTouched))">Please enter your Last Name</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input formControlName="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                                <span class="for-signuperror" [hidden]="!(signupuser.controls.email.invalid && (signupuser.controls.email.touched || signUpFormTouched))">Please enter your Email</span>
                                <span class="for-signuperror" *ngIf="sign_up_errors.email">
                                    {{sign_up_errors.email[0]}}
                                </span>

                                <span class="help-inline error danger for-signuperror " *ngIf="sign_up_errors.email">{{sign_up_errors.email}}</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input formControlName="password" type="password" #passwordEye class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-eye eyeicon" (click)="showPassword(passwordEye)"></i></span>
                                <span class="for-signuperror" [hidden]="!(signupuser.controls.password.invalid && (signupuser.controls.password.touched || signUpFormTouched))">Please enter your Password</span>
                                <span class="help-inline error danger for-signuperror" *ngIf="sign_up_errors.password">{{sign_up_errors.password[0]}}</span>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                        </form>
```

signup.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';
import { ApiService } from '../service/api.service';
import { ShareService } from './../service/share.service';
//import * as jQuery from 'jquery';


// declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css'],
  providers: [ApiService]
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
    signupuser: FormGroup;
    isProcessing:boolean = false;   
    signUpFormTouched: boolean = false;
    sign_up_errors:any; 
    dialog_title:string;
    dialog_message:string;
    showDialog:boolean = false;
    email: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    Password: string;
    Location: string;
    error: string;
    errors: any;

    visible:any;
    maxlength: number;


  constructor(private router: Router,
                      fb: FormBuilder,
              private apiService: ApiService,
              private shareService: ShareService) { 

        this.signupuser = fb.group({
                    "email": ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required,CustomValidators.email])],
                    "password": ["", Validators.required],
                    "first_name" : ["", Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')],
                    "last_name" : ["", Validators.required]
                });
                    this.sign_up_errors = {
                    "email": "",
                    "password": ""
                };

  }

  showPassword( passwordEye: any) {
    passwordEye.type = passwordEye.type === 'password' ?  'text' : 'password';


  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onClose($event){
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    } 

  signup(signupuser){
    //console.log(signupuser.value); 
    this.signUpFormTouched = true;

        if(signupuser.invalid){
            return;
        }

        let post_data:any = signupuser.value;


        if(!post_data.access_code_selected){
            post_data.access_token = "";
        }
        this.isProcessing = true;

        this.apiService.post('auth/signup',post_data)
        .then( (data) => {

            this.signupuser.reset();
            this.showDialog = true;
            this.dialog_title = "Please check your Email Inbox";
      this.dialog_message = "We have sent you an email to verify your Account.";

            this.isProcessing = false;
        })
        .catch((res) => {

            this.isProcessing = false;
            if(typeof res.error != 'undefined'){
                this.sign_up_errors = res.error.errors;
            }
            /*else{
                this.sign_up_errors = [res.error.message];
            }*/
        });
 }

}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ng",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet",
    "compile_@agm_core": "babel node_modules/@agm/core -d node_modules/@agm/core --presets es2015",
    "postinstall": "npm run compile_@agm_core"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-trim-directive": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786995/avoid-angular2-to-systematically-submit-form-on-button-click/40103456#40103456?

Comment: provide your package.json too. It's working on your local but not on server. It means there is something wrong in version of packages.

Comment: hi @SandipJaiswal, i added package.json. please go through it once.

Comment: Just edit following line your package.json 
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.0", and let me know is it working.

Comment: check out this im too facing the same problem this might help you https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21173

Comment: you have `CORS` issue when signing up, your domain over `http` and your `auth service` over `https`...
Failed to load http://gaapi.snsepro.com/api/auth/signup: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ga.snsepro.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

I have find out same problems to others,
Might be this solution will work for you

1 - add uglify-es@3.2.2 to dependencies array in package.json

2 - delete node_modules and dist

3 - npm install

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
```

when you put a button under the forum just select the Button Type as `button` instead of `submit` as above code.

If you did not declare a type you must declare a type as `button` because button element with no type attribute specified represents the same thing as a button element with its type attribute set to `submit`.

Hope it WORKS!