# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in scripts.bundle.js

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm using Angular 5.1.0, Node 8.9.3 and CLI 1.6.0
I want to add rm-emoji-picker ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rm-emoji-picker)) to my project - it requires jQuery.

I received message error:

> scripts.bundle.js:20371 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

it points to:

```
import $ from "jquery"; // ERROR MARKED THERE
import EmojiEditor from "./EmojiEditor";
import EmojiCategory from "./EmojiCategory";
import Converters from "./Converters";
import Tooltip from "rm-tooltip";
```

I tried to solve this problem using this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979463/4955934) topic, but nothing has changed.

My angular-cli.json looklike that:

```
      "styles": [
    "../node_modules/vis/dist/vis-network.min.css",
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",
    "../node_modules/rm-emoji-picker/dist/emojipicker.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js",
    "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/python/python.js",
    "../node_modules/rm-emoji-picker/src/js/EmojiPicker.js"
  ],
```

Comment: Whole error trace please.

Comment: @trichetriche added

Comment: No you didn't. That's still the first line.

Comment: @trichetriche it is the only one line which I got

Comment: Then how do you know where the error comes from ...